# How do I print the point array with integers?

Tags: java, arrays

```
//imports and class block trimmed
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Point[] xy = new Point[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < xy.length; i++) {

        Point c = new Point((int) (Math.random() * 100),
                (int) (Math.random() * 100));

        xy[i] = c;
    }

    Arrays.sort(xy);

    for (int j = 0; j < xy.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(xy[j]);
    }

}
```

I get an output of 100 statements like "Point@d46ca6". I need it to display integers. I have two other classes titled Point and CompareY.  How do I print the array items in xy as integers?

Answer (score 3):

Override the `toString()` method in your `Point` class:

```
class Point {
    // your code ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: package-private `toString()` method. That is something new.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `toString()` method of the `Point` class to print the numbers nicely:

```
System.out.println(xy[j].toString());
```

If this is your own `Point` class, you can always (and probably should) write an override to `toString()` that prints them out nicely. (See nem's post)